# C# get XElement attributes from XDocument with treeview path

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, treeview

I'm trying to write a winforms application that displays any opened XML files nodes (and only it's nodes) in  TreeView and displays the attributes of the selected node separately (by selected i mean selected in the TreeView) (displayed in a listbox for example). I tried to achieve this by using the following code but it throws an exception saying:'family\parent' has an invalid token.

```
private void TView__AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(businessLayer.InputFilepath);
    XElement myElement = doc.Root.XPathSelectElement(TView_.SelectedNode.FullPath);
    try
    {
        foreach (var attribute in myElement.Attributes())
        {
           listBox1.Items.Add(attribute.Value); 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {  
    }
}
```

I'm using the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<family>
  <parent>
    <id>grandfather</id>
    <parent>
      <id>father</id>
      <parent>
        <id>brother</id>
        <child>
          <id>niece</id>
        </child>
      </parent>
      <parent>
        <is>me</is>
        <child>
          <id>son</id>
        </child>
        <child>
          <id>dauhter</id>
        </child>
      </parent>
      <child>
        <id>sister</id>
      </child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
      <id>uncle</id>
      <parent>
        <id>cousin sister</id>
        <child>
          <id>second cousin</id>
        </child>
      </parent>
      <child>
        <id>cousin brother</id>
      </child>
    </parent>
  </parent>
</family>
```

I have no clue about what else i could try so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you iterating over attributes if you don't have any attributes as part of the elements in your XML? It's likely to return `NULL`. Looks like a mistake in XML design.

Comment: I meant to fix that, but somehow managed forget it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid that exception you have to replace every double backslash to a slash in the path of you XML file.

```
string path = treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.Replace('\\', '/');
XElement myElement = doc.XPathSelectElement(path);
```